# Commit individual lines in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I'm using Workbench, but if there's a command line solution for this or some extension, I'm open to that as well.

I'm constantly working in config files per environment (**working in .NET, so please no answers a la "change your config files" etc**) and at times I need to commit specific updates to the file. I've seen this behavior in Github for Mac client, but is anything like this available in Mercurial/Workbench? e.g.

`web.config`

```
config value="123"
whatever blah blah
```

change both lines e.g.

```
config value="42"
whatever
```

My goal is to commit only line 2 (**whatever**) while *not committing* line 1 (**config value="42"**)

Answer (score 4):

You probably need [`RecordExtension`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RecordExtension) which is shipped with Mercurial but has to be enabled to be used.

Comment: Record can't see any change smaller than a diff `hunk`, so consecutive lines will be treated as one single change.  While some diff implementations let you override the hunk size, Record doesn't have that sharp of a knife when splitting hairs.

Answer (score 3):

The [Record Extention](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RecordExtension) isn't up to the job in this case. It will lump the two changes into a single hunk which you can include or not, but it won't allow you to split them.

What you need is the [CRecord Extention](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CrecordExtension), as that allows you to select individual lines. It's also a nicer interface.

Edit: Since writing this, Record and CRecord have been folded into core. `commit -i` is now equivalent to `record`, and if you add this to your `.hgrc` the record commands will use the nicer interface.

```
[ui]
interface=curses
```

Comment: According to https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CrecordExtension CRecord is included, but I can't figure out how to use it with TortoiseHg. Is it only available with command line interface?

Comment: Yes, CRecord is a command line interface. I don't know much about TortoiseHG as I don't use it, but a quick look at the documentation seems to suggest it has a similar feature. [Change Selection](http://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commit.html#change-selection)

Comment: I am using Git Gui and thinking of switching to TortoiseHg. I often use the stage hunk and stage line commands. According to the page you mention and all the documentation I was able to find, TortoiseHg can only do the stage hunk, not the stage line, so I will keep Git. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`hg record` ou `hg commit -i` will do the job, but you have to use the `e` command in order to manually edit the patch.
In your case, you will have to replace:

```
-config value="123"
-whatever blah blah
+config value="42"
+whatever
```

to

```
 config value="123"
-whatever blah blah
+whatever
```

It is not the best UI, but it does the job.